# AppDelegate, DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional What does it mean?

Tags: swift, appdelegate

The app build successfully with no error in debugging area, but immediately stops and bring me to this;

[image: error message]

I'm not sure what to make of the error. I can only guess its in the AppDelegate.swift, somewhere along DidFinishLanchingWithOptions.

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Sorry, not smart enough to figure out this probably trivial error to you guys

**UPDATE:**

I've tried the suggestion by user mstysf below, but the same problem occur?  Am i doing it wrong or missing something?

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {

    if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {

        let challengesController = navigationController.topViewController as ChallengesViewController

        unarchiveDataSource()

        if let dataSource = challengeDataSource {
            challengesController.challengeDataSource = dataSource
        } else {
            loadDefaultChallenges()
            challengesController.challengeDataSource = challengeDataSource
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: seems like my `let challengesController = navigationController.topViewController as ChallengesViewController` need to be unwrapped or something? i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It means the `navigationController` is `nil`. You should handle with it like this:

```
if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
    // do your work here
}
```

It builds successfully because compiler trusts you `navigationController` won't be `nil` and does not check it. That's the point of implicitly unwrapped optional type. In the runtime if it is `nil` then your app crashes. That's the danger of implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I'm still in the process of learning. 
I've tried what you suggested, but the same problem occur?